# Are there any automated techniques one can use to gather data online for a dataset?

Tags: web-crawling

I am a developer myself and would like to use latest technologies to build some open data datasets.

I would like to know if you are aware of any techniques or algorithm one can use to automate gather data on the internet instead of manually doing something following,

- Google search and then trying to gather data
- Put in Excel
- Clean data using whatever language you require

I am fairly new to this so I might be thinking it completely wrong.

Comment: You should search for 'scraping websites'. There are plenty of tools but which one you can use best depends on the structure of the websites. (Not that I assume that *data on the internet*. Your question is unclear)

Comment: Your 1st and 2nd paragraphs together suggest that you want to 'republish' connected data. Beware of copyright issues.

Comment: 'Not that I assume that data on the internet' -> 'Note that I assume that data on the internet are websites'